# Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame error in HTTP POST request SSJS marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, httprequest, httppost

I am trying to post a request to my site and I am using SSJS HTTP post method. But the POST request is throwing error ""

> Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.

Im not sure what i am missing here also i just have the content type as header no other headers are required for my request. Kindly find my code below,

```
   var inputjson="{\"username\":\"test@test.com\",\"password\":\"testtbot1\",\"Privatekey\":\"0lemon9087\"}";
   var url="https://mysandbox.com/api/Rest/v1/Authenticate";
   var content = [0];
   var headername="[Content-Type]";
   var headervalues="[application/json]";
   var result = HTTP.Post(url,"application/json",inputjson,headername,headervalues);
```

I have tried Stringify payload but its also throwing the same error.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

var url = “https://mysandbox.com/api/Rest/v1/Authenticate”;
var payload = {
        username: "test@test.com",
        password: "testtbot1",
        privatekey: “0lemon9087”
    };
var contentType = “application/json”;

try {
   var request = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
} catch (error) {
    Write(error);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Array of header name and values are the required parameters

Answer (score 0):

There was a syntax issue, instead of array of headers i have declared as string so fixing the syntax solved the issue

```
var headername=[];
var headervalues=[];
```