# Unable to create Case object with SSJS

Tags: api, ssjs, httppost

I am able to create a Case in SalesCloud using Postman. However, with the same JSON payload this is failing from my CloudPage using SSJS (note that I retrieve the token successfully in the same page)

When I try

```
  var result = HTTP.Post(endpoint, "application/json", payload, ["Cache-Control", "Authorization"], ["no-cache", "Bearer " + token]);
```

I get
{"message":"Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.","description":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame. - from mscorlib\r\n\r\n"}

I also tried by converting the payload to form data (this worked for the token retrieval..)

```
 var result = HTTP.Post(endpoint, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", payload, ["Cache-Control", "Authorization"], ["no-cache", "Bearer " + token]);
```

But I get error
{"message":"An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPPost function call.  See inner exception for details.","description":"ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPPost function call.  See inner exception for details.\r\n  Error Code: OMM_FUNC_EXEC_ERROR\r\n - from Jint --> \r\n\r\n --- inner exception 1---\r\n\r\nSystem.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type. - from System\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"}

What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame error in HTTP POST request SSJS marketing cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/285119/unable-to-retrieve-security-descriptor-for-this-frame-error-in-http-post-request)

Comment: No :(, I tried the same , application/json and Stringify(payload) but I get
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Comment: Any particular reason for not using the native Ampscript functions for creating records via the connector?

Comment: That's a good question, we are not allowed to do it for cases, business reasons

Answer (score 0):

It's solved:

1. Blank space after Bearer is needed.
2. Stringify the payload

   > ```
   >  var payload =  Stringify(payload)
   >     var result = HTTP.Post(endpoint, "application/json", payload, ["Cache-Control", "Authorization"], ["no-cache", "Bearer " + token]); 
   >
   >       if (result.StatusCode == 200) {
   >                     Write("Case created " + Stringify(Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Response[0])));          
   >
   >       } else { Write ("</br> oh, there was an error "); }
   > ```